# Preferred way of writing constraints parameters in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Which way of writing constraints parameter is preferred in grails - 
 i)without first brackets

```
class User {
...
static constraints = {
    login size: 5..15, blank: false, unique: true
    password size: 5..15, blank: false
}
}
```

ii) with first brackets

```
class User {
...
static constraints = {
    login (size: 5..15, blank: false, unique: true)
    password (size: 5..15, blank: false)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of style. Both are 100% valid and Grails/Groovy doesn't care. You should refer to your style guide for your code base. Which should be provided to you by your architect.